# OpenCV filestorage error

Tags: c++, xml, opencv, export, file-storage

Hello I would like to export 3 histograms (rgb) to a .xml file then read from .xml and save to another matrix.

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat org,cmp, dst;

    /// Load image
    org = imread("arrowr.png");
    cmp = imread("cat.jpg");

    if (!org.data)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    /// Separate the image in 3 places ( B, G and R )
    Mat bgr_planes_org[3] = {};         //zmena z vector<Mat> bgr_planes;
    split(org, bgr_planes_org);

    /// Establish the number of bins
    int histSize = 256;

    /// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
    float range[] = { 0, 256 };
    const float* histRange = { range };

    bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;

    Mat b_hist_org, g_hist_org, r_hist_org;


    /// Compute the histograms:
    calcHist(&bgr_planes_org[0], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist_org, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);
    calcHist(&bgr_planes_org[1], 1, 0, Mat(), g_hist_org, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);
    calcHist(&bgr_planes_org[2], 1, 0, Mat(), r_hist_org, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);

    // Draw the histograms for B, G and R
    int hist_w = 512; int hist_h = 400;
    int bin_w = cvRound((double)hist_w / histSize);

    Mat histImage(hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));

    /// Normalize the result to [ 0, histImage.rows ]
    normalize(b_hist_org, b_hist_org, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());
    normalize(g_hist_org, g_hist_org, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());
    normalize(r_hist_org, r_hist_org, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());

    Mat mat_r, mat_g, mat_b;
    string filename = "test.xml";
    FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::WRITE);
    fs << "blu" << b_hist_org;
    fs << "grn" << g_hist_org;
    fs << "red" << r_hist_org;
    fs.release();

    FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::READ);
    fs["blu"] >> mat_b;
    fs["red"] >> mat_r;
    fs["grn"] >> mat_g;
    fs.release();

        cout << mat_r << endl;
        cout << mat_g << endl;
        cout << mat_b << endl;

        system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run it it throws me this "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF96ECA8A5C in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000A4D911BF40."

I think its something with `FileStorage::READ`. When i comment the section where i read from .xml it works without error. It also works when i put only one matrix in and then read it .

I also noticed that in the .xml file i have the exported data like this:

```
<blu type_id="opencv-matrix">
<rows>256</rows>
<cols>1</cols>
<dt>f</dt>
<data>
"blue matrix data"
</data></blu>
<blu>grn</blu>
<blu type_id="opencv-matrix">
<rows>256</rows>
<cols>1</cols>
<dt>f</dt>
<data>
"green matrix data"    
</data></blu>
<red type_id="opencv-matrix">
<rows>256</rows>
<cols>1</cols>
<dt>f</dt>
<data>
"red matrix data"
</data></red>
</opencv_storage>
```

Why is there this `<blu>grn</blu>`? I want my green matrix with the header `<grn>`. Why is the `grn` under the `<blu>` header?

According to openCV i should have three headers for each matrix. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html

Any help/link to solution would be cool.

Comment: This works ok for me (except that you need to change the name of `fs` the second time). Please be sure to post the exact code that produces the error. See how to do a [mcve]

Comment: Also, such errors usually are due to using debug libs in release, or viceversa. Or libs compiled with a different compiler. Please show your lib path, and you VS version

Comment: Wow Miki , you were right! I had both libs in debug and release too. Solution explorer>Proerties>Linker>Input>Aditional Dependencies and in release i left only the opencv_world310.lib, in the debug opencv_world310d.lib.(visual studio 2015)

No errors and the .xml generates fine too. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct (aside that you redefine `FileStorage fs...`, just change the name).

Usually, if you have an `Unhandled exception` error in OpenCV, it means that you're using debug libraries in release, or viceversa.

---

From the comments it turns out that this was in fact the issue. Be sure to link only to `opencv_world310.lib` in Release and to `opencv_world310d.lib` in Debug.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to load a malformed XML (not escaping an ampersand); I solved correcting my XML file, using an [online checker](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/) to catch the error. BTW I find a bit suicidal to release such a poorly robust code to the public.